# RegisterAssembly даёт ошибку FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, com

Есть библиотека классов, класс в которой помечен как ComVisible.
Этот класс в работе использует Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, который в виде dll лежит рядом с dll моей библиотеки классов.

При использовании такого кода

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(pathToAssembly);
RegistrationServices regAsm = new RegistrationServices();
bool bResult = regAsm.RegisterAssembly(asm, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
```

Получаем ексепшен FileNotFoundException

```
{"Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку \"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, 
Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342\" 
либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.":"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, 
Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"}
```

Фюжен лог показывает, что сборка ищется в каталоге вызывающей программы. Каким образом можно указать, что сборку надо искать там, откуда открывали сборку для регистрации? Я так понял, что зависимости грузятся в контекст вызывающей программы, по умолчанию.

Comment: Вы не должны использовать LoadFile. Попробуйте вместо этого LoadFrom: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context/

Comment: Спасибо, в итоге к этому и пришёл, изучив код regasm и почитав документацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать определить полный путь до COM-компонента и загружать Oracle.ManagedDataAccess по этому пути:

```
string currentAssemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string currentAssemblyDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentAssemblyPath);
string pathToAssembly = Path.Combine(currentAssemblyDir, "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll");
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(pathToAssembly);
// ...
```

---

**С учетом новых сведений**. Вам придется вручную управлять разрешением зависимостей сборок. Это осуществляется через событие `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`. Событие вызывается в том случае, если CLR не смог автоматически разрешить зависимости.

Небольшой пример:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
    // В вашем случае в args.Name будет лежать строка
    // Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
    // Также сюда вам необходимо каким-то образом передать каталог, где лежит COM-компонент
    // и зависимая сборка (например, считать через реестр: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{guid_вашего_компонента}\InprocServer32)
    // Пусть comPath - каталог, где лежит ваша зависимая сборка

    string depAssemblyFileName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
    string depAssemblyPath = Path.Combine(comPath, depAssemblyFileName);
    return Assembly.Load(depAssemblyPath);
};
```

Код необходимо добавить до вашего кода регистрации.

Comment: Возможно я немного не точно написал. Моя сборка грузится нормально, но при попытке зарегистрировать, ругается на зависимую сборку, которую регистратор ищет в папке вызывающей программы, а не там, где лежит моя сборка.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Код утилиты regasm показал такой же метод. Ваш совет утвердил меня во мнении оправильности пути. Спасибо.